# ¿Cómo acceder a datos concretos de un archivo CSV en Python sin utilizar librerías?

Tags: python, bucle-for, csv

Tengo un archivo CSV sobre satélites del cual tengo que iterar mediante un bucle for para averiguar, entre otras cosas, cuántos satélites de uso 'Civil' tiene el archivo. El problema es que cuando quiero acceder a algún dato en concreto me suelen salir los errores TypeError: object is not subscriptable o TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Por ahora he realizado lo siguiente:

`satelites = open("UCS-Satellite-Database.csv")`

```
for i in satelites:
    print(i)
```

Esto lo he hecho para ver las filas del archivo. Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema viene cuando quiero iterar sobre la variable 'Civil' o, también, sobre una columna en concreto, pues siempre me da error. Para ello estoy poniendo lo siguiente:

Para la variable 'Civil':

```
for i in satelites:
    print(i['Civil'])
```

Para la segunda columna del archivo, la cual se llama 'Users':

```
for i in satelites:
    print(i['Users'])
```

Ambos bucles me dan error. También he probado otras formas de iterar pero con el mismo resultado de error. Si alguien sabe qué podría estar fallando y me lo dice lo agradezco.

Comment: Puedes realizar un split. Por ejemplo arr=i.split(","), y después accedes a cada valor con el índice del arreglo. print(arr[0])

Comment: ¿no puedes usar `csv` para leer los ficheros? Su DictReader es muy útil

Comment: En principio tengo que hacerlo sin utilizar librerías pero buscaré información a ver cómo funciona. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando la función `open` estás abriendo el fichero en modo texto, por lo que, en tu caso, al iterar sobre la variable `satelites` estás iterando sobre cada línea de texto del fichero.

En este caso, lo único que puedes hacer es saltarte la primera línea, que es la que contiene las cabeceras, por ejemplo utilizando `satelites = open("UCS-Satellite-Database.csv")[1:]` y luego utilizar la función `split` con el separador que haya en tu fichero CSV (normalmente ',' o ';') sobre cada línea de texto (la variable `i` en tu caso) para separar la línea en los distintos elementos definidos en la cabecera.

El tratamiento de un CSV (o cualquier fichero de texto) a mano es tedioso, por eso existen librerías que se encargan de tratar los formatos comunes como csv, json o yml.

Comment: No se por qué pero cuando intento importar el archivo mediante `satelites = open("UCS-Satellite-Database.csv")[1:]` obtengo un TypeError "object is not subscriptable".

Comment: para leer desde la 2.ª línea sería algo así como `with open(fichero) as f: next(f) lines = f.readlines()`

Comment: Perdón, Álvaro, eso es porque open devuelve un tipo file. Deberías transformarlo con la función readlines(), que devuelve efectivamente una lista. La solucion de fedorqui también debería funcionar